# How to remove border components in Python 2.7 using Opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to remove the components which are touching the border of the image.

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.10 and Python 2.7.

I have done HSV conversion and THRESHOLD_BINARY of the image, next I want to remove the components (objects) which are touching to border of the image.

It was explained in Matlab here - http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/09/04/clearing-border-components/

but I want to do in Python using OpenCV.

Please explain me the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct method in openCV to do that. You can write a function using the method **floodFill** and loop over for border pixels as seed points.

`floodFill(dstImg,seed,Scalar (0));`

where:

**dstImg** : Output with border removed.

**seed** : [(x,y) points] All the border co-ordinates

**Scalar(0)** : The color to be filled if a connected region towards a seed point is found. Hence (0) as your case is to fill it as black.

Sample:

```
int totalRows = srcImg.rows;
int totalCols = srcImg.cols;
int strt = 0, flg = 0;
int iRows = 0, jCols = 0;
while (iRows < srcImg.rows)
{
    if (flg ==1)
        totalRows = -1;
    Point seed(strt,iRows);     
    iRows++;
    floodFill(dstImg,seed,Scalar (0));
    if (iRows == totalRows)
    {
        flg++;
        iRows = 0;
        strt = totalCols - 1;
    }
}
```

Similarly do modify it for columns.
Hope It helps.

Comment: Thank you sriram for the reply, can u show me the simple code for replacing border components using cv2. function and how to use this floodFill

Comment: Answer updated with code...! You need to add similar code for columns as well. Try to implement by yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but you could enclose each contour in a bounding rectangle and test whether the coordinates of this rectangle fall on or outside the boundary of the image (im)

```
for c in contours:
    include = True  
    # omit this contour if it touches the edge of the image
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)       
    if x <= 1 or y <=1:
        include = False                 
    if x+w+1 >= im.shape[1] or y+h+1 >= im.shape[0]:
        include = False
    # draw the contour
    if include == True:
        cv2.drawContours(im, [c], -1, (255, 0, 255), 2)
```