# python opencv crop using contour hierarchy

Tags: python, opencv

I was looking to remove the borders from the below image 
[image]

what I have tried till now is using OpenCV to get edges
code:

```
def autocrop(image, threshold=0):
    """Crops any edges below or equal to threshold

    Crops blank image to 1x1.

    Returns cropped image.

    """
    if len(image.shape) == 3:
        flatImage = np.max(image, 2)
    else:
        flatImage = image
    assert len(flatImage.shape) == 2

    rows = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 0) > threshold)[0]
    if rows.size:
        cols = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 1) > threshold)[0]
        image = image[cols[0]: cols[-1] + 1, rows[0]: rows[-1] + 1]
    else:
        image = image[:1, :1]

    return image

no_border = autocrop(new_image)


cv2.imwrite('no_border.png',no_border)
```

the result is this image , next how to remove those boxes

[image]

Update :

I have found that the solution works for a white background but when I change the background color border are not removed

[image]

**Edited**

I have tried the solution on this image

[image]

But the result was like this

[image]

How I can achieve a complete removal of the boundary boxes .

Comment: possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465433

Comment: I have written a concise code to identify the characters using the concept of hierarchy in contours. There is no need to write elaborate code to crop and chop. See the answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this we use [`floodFill`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717) function.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # read image and convert to gray
    img = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # threshold the gray image to binarize, and negate it
    _,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

    # find external contours of all shapes
    _,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # create a mask for floodfill function, see documentation
    h,w,_ = img.shape
    mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2), np.uint8)

    # determine which contour belongs to a square or rectangle
    for cnt in contours:
        poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
        if len(poly) == 4:
            # if the contour has 4 vertices then floodfill that contour with black color
            cnt = np.vstack(cnt).squeeze()
            _,binary,_,_ = cv2.floodFill(binary, mask, tuple(cnt[0]), 0)
    # convert image back to original color
    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)        

    cv2.imshow('Image', binary)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

Comment: thank you very much it works.
small edit because `i` is not defined

Comment: what do you think a solution for the background color?

Comment: @ahmedosama Your new image has white foreground already. So no need for the 2 lines: `binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)`. Comment out both lines.

Comment: sorry the new image is the blue background the white background is the output from the code. i will remove it to make everything clear

Comment: I added the new image. the code works fine in the upper part will lower part appears with black ground 
this the output when i remove `binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)` link https://imgur.com/a/20Go16w

Comment: @ahmedosama Do you want the upper part **and** the lower part? If so then you should JeruLuke's answer. It's much simpler.

Comment: I want to remove borders from the new image. is this possible ?

Comment: @ahmedosama Yes, it's possible. Divide the image in two. Compute upper part with `cv2.bitwise_not()` and the lower part without it.

Comment: thanks , but i found strange thing this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyyRu.png the boxes is not removed from the D letter

Answer (score 5):

There is another to find the characters within the image. This using the concept of **hierarchy** in contours.

The implementation is in python:

```
path = r'C:\Desktop\Stack'
filename = '2.png'

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename), 1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

_, contours2, hierarchy2 = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Notice that in the `cv2.findContours()` function is passed in the `RETR_CCOMP` parameter to store contours according to their different levels of hierarchy. Hierarchy is useful when one contour lies inside another contour, thus enabling and parent-child relationship. `RETR_CCOMP` helps identify this relationship.

```
img2 = img.copy()
l = []
for h in hierarchy2[0]:
    if h[0] > -1 and h[2] > -1:
        l.append(h[2])
```

In the snippet above I am passing all contours that have a child into the list `l`. Using `l` I am drawing those contours in the snippet below.

```
for cnt in l:
    if cnt > 0:
        cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours2[cnt]], 0, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
```

[image]

Have a look at the [DOCUMENTATION HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) to learn more about hierarchy in contours.

Comment: This is a nice answer!